# Get active a tags switching to work with pushState?

Tags: javascript, html, nav, pushstate

I have a single page website and I am using an ACTIVE class on the nav to highlight the links in the NAV.

The javascript to make nav links active:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.inner-nav li a').click(function(e) {

        $('.inner-nav li.active').removeClass('active');

        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

window.onscroll = () => {
    var current = "parent";

    sections.forEach((page-section) => {
        const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
        if (pageYOffset >= sectionTop ) {
        current = section.getAttribute("main"); }
    });

    navLi.forEach((li) => {
        li.classList.remove("active");
        if (li.classList.contains(current)) {
        li.classList.add("active");
        }
    });
};
```

The NAV html:

```
<div class="inner-nav desktop-nav">
    <ul class="clearlist scroll-nav local-scroll">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" onclick="ChangeUrl('Home', '/');">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" onclick="ChangeUrl('About', '/about');">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#features" onclick="ChangeUrl('Features', '/features');">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news" onclick="ChangeUrl('Blog', '/blog');">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mail-list" onclick="ChangeUrl('Newsletter', '/newsletter');">Newsletter</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the js for the pushState.

```
function ChangeUrl(title, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}
```

I am trying to make it to where when you scroll down the pushState will change the URL in the address bar, to match the section it is in.

For example:

If I click on About in the nav it highlights About, and adds /about to the end of the URL.

But when I scroll down to the About section, the About link highlights but doesn't add the /about to the URL in the address bar.

Is there any JS magic that can make this work?

Comment: I tried adding onload="ChangeUrl('Newsletter', '/newsletter');" to the section tags and it didn't work. I tried onScroll as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out, if anyone else is looking to do this, here you go.

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#home")) { window.history.pushState("state", "Home", "/"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#about")) { window.history.pushState("state", "About", "/about"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#features")) { window.history.pushState("state", "Features", "/features"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#news")) { window.history.pushState("state", "Blog", "/blog"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#mail-list")) { window.history.pushState("state", "Newsletter", "/newsletter"); return; }
});
```

I created a new js file and included it under the jQuery, I noticed it also requires the onScroll so,

```
<section class="page-section about-bg" id="about" onScroll="ChangeUrl('About', '/about');">
```